# Plural terms and Sitecore lucene

Tags: content-search, lucene

Sitecore 8.2 U6

I have been experimenting with the Sitecore stemming analyzer.

> Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.StandardAnalyzerWithStemming

But it isn't perfect. It has trouble with natural words that end with `s`, like Christmas. It just won't find it unless I search for Christma*.

I am wondering what other people are doing for pluralized searches in Sitecore. We do not have SOLR in yet. That not on the roadmap for a few months.

Comment: So are you looking for something that will match `apple` with both `apple` and `apples`? But then can handle `Christmas` too?

Comment: Yeah. If someone types in Park, to get back results that have parks in it also. Its the promise of stemming to find the root of words and index just the root word, not the actually words. So all parks and park get indexed as park. When someone searches for park or parks, the term gets cut down to the root and that is queried against the index.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on how adventurous you feel ;-)

What will improve things for you, is if you either upgrade your Lucene version (your Sitecore version ships with Lucene 3.0 or so - you need, as far as I can tell, at least version 4.6).

In there, you will find the `EnglishAnalyzer` which is an extension of the Porter Stemming algorithm to handle "English stuff" like English Possessive form.

Alternatively, if you don't feel like upgrading Lucene, maybe you can jimmy it into your solution and use the analyzer anyway. Sources are available.

https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/tree/master/src/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common/Analysis/En

But it's never going to be perfect, or even come close to what SOLR can do. If you're serious about searching - and your question indicates that you are - it's time to trade up on your search technology.

**edited to add**

Leaving all tech in place, you could try experimenting with Fuzzy Searching instead. Performance isn't great in Lucene 3, but it might still get you a bit further.

Try searching for `Christmas~` and see what kind of results you get.

- [Lucene Query Parser Syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html)
- [Snowball: A language for stemming algorithms](http://snowball.tartarus.org/texts/introduction.html)